# How to prevent cart empty after checkout payment failure in magento 2.2.5?

Tags: cart, payment, magento-2.2.5

In **Magento 2.2.5**, after payment failure cart is going empty. I want to keep this, that if payment failed cart will not be empty, that will show last cart items.

I'm using the PayUMoney Payment Method. How can I do this?

I get a lot of example of this problem on **Magento 1.9** version but didn't get any suitable solution for **Magento 2.2.5**.

Please help me, how I solve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample code for reactivate quote when payment is failed. This is a controller where it redirect after payment failure. You need to use it in your payment module and update the code according to your requirement or module structure.

```
<?php 
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Controller\Order;

class Failure extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    ...
    protected $_quoteFactory;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    ...
    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        ...
    ){
        ...
        $this->_quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        ...
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $this->_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            $this->messageManager->addWarningMessage('Payment Failed.');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. But unable to do this.
in the file path -- **vendor/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Failure.php** in this page I tried to implement your above code. But it's not working for me. I tried to implement in my payment method extension that is **PayUM**. But didn't find any failure page. I think this extension using Magento default failure function.
Please help, what I did wrong.

Comment: I followed the same code in the failure page payment method but it did not work for me. always items are removing from the cart.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solutions for **Magento 2.3.5**. Please override **Failure.php**(Core file path: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage) and change ***public function*** as below

```
public function execute()
{
   
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
    
    $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
        $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        //$this->messageManager->addWarningMessage('Payment Failed.');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't works at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore your order with

```
$this->_checkoutSession->restoreOrder()
```